# Accessing infinite nested children object

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Wanted to know how can we access infinitely nested object in JS?

Consider this example given to be my interviewer

You have an object with a Parent and infinitely nested children

```
[ 
 { 
   name: "Jack",
   age: "98" ,
   profession: "doctor
   children: [
               {
                 name: "Varun",
                 age: "80"
                 profession: "scientist"
                 children: [
                             {
                                name: "Ishan"
                                age: "62",
                                profession: "teacher
                                children: [{....
                                 .....
                                 .....[{
                                       name: "Rahul",
                                       age: "23",
                                       profession: "engineer"
                                      children: [{
                                                  .....
```

I need to find the name corresponding where profession is "engineer" and how deep that given object is nested.

Note: Number of children to be considered here is infinite.

Question: Can someone help me in figuring out how I can do it **with recursion** and **without recursion**

**update:** He gave me a hint to use divide and conquer

**Update:** Based on the solution by Bary, I tried something like this

```
let infiniteArray = [ 
    { 
      name: "Jack",
      age: "98" ,
      profession: "doctor",
      children: [
                  {
                    name: "Varun",
                    age: "80",
                    profession: "scientist",
                    children: [
                                {
                                   name: "Ishan",
                                   age: "62",
                                   profession: "teacher"
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        }
]


function isTheItem(item) {
   if (item["profession"] === "teacher") return item
    return false
 }


 function walk(collection) {
    return collection.find(item => isTheItem(item) || walk(item.children));
  }
```

But when I console.log it, i.e `console.log(walk(infiniteArray))`, it is logging the entire infiniteArray and I understand why but I went it to return just the name corresponding to profession. Any help on how I can achieve it?

```
  name: "Ishan",
        age: "62",
        profession: "teacher"
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There's two directions walking through your collection
* sibling
* nested

so you can iterate this sibling items with regular array iterator and recursively walk through the children of each item.

```
function isTheItem(item) {
   return ...;
}

function walk(collection) {
  return collection.find(item => isTheItem(item) || walk(item.children));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide and conquer algorithms usually have more to do with sorting values in an array (during an interview process). If you were sorting by age or something, I could see that being a hint. But there's no way to really divide and conquer when searching for a key value pair of an infinite number of nested objects. You have to search through n number of values until you find the result. Any dividing of the object doesn't necessarily improve efficiency with a random key value pair stored that you want to find.

**More experienced devs correct me if I'm wrong here**

Barry Gane has a good start to the code you would write for the actual application of this.

Comment: There's also a lodash/underscore function out there for searching for key value pairs. They're asking to see you handle algorithm related questions, but it's probably worth some brownie points to mention that in real practice you'd use a lodash function for readability.